# VB Script to change or strip out special characters

Tags: vbscript

I have a small VB script (see below) which i found via google, what it does is find a this string (H*699557/1A) in an XML file and renames the filename to that string, This works brilliantly until it encounters a special character (As in the string example) where it then stops.

Could someone please help me to remove the special characters, any help appreciated.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "C:\vbs"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)

Set regEx = New RegExp  
regEx.Pattern = ".*<SuppliersInvoiceNumber>(.*?)</SuppliersInvoiceNumber>.*"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True 
regEx.MultiLine = True

For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileName = strFile.Name 
    If InStr(strFileName ,"USI") > 0 Then
        Set objFile=objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName)
        strData = objFile.ReadAll 
        Set objFile=Nothing
        Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(strData)
        For Each objMatch In colMatches
           strNew = Split(objMatch.Submatches(0),"\")
           strNewFile = strNew(0)
           strFile.Name = strNewFile & ".xml"
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example of when it stops? Which special characters cause it to fail? Can you post the error message?

Comment: Hi Nathan, The string that i am using to change the file name as these " */ " characters in it, I need to remove these before  it renames the file. The error is : Line: 18, Char 6, Error: Invalid procedure call or argument, Code: 800A0005, Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error.

Comment: On which line number does that correspond to in your code above?

Comment: On the following strFile.Name = strNewFile & ".xml"

Comment: I've posted a solution. If you find it helpful please accept it and upvote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "C:\vbs"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)

Set regEx = New RegExp  
regEx.Pattern = ".*<SuppliersInvoiceNumber>(.*?)</SuppliersInvoiceNumber>.*"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True 
regEx.MultiLine = True

For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileName = strFile.Name 
    If InStr(strFileName ,"USI") > 0 Then
        Set objFile=objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName)
        strData = objFile.ReadAll 
        Set objFile=Nothing
        Set colMatches = regEx.Execute(strData)
        For Each objMatch In colMatches
           strNew = Split(objMatch.Submatches(0),"\")
           strNewFile = strNew(0)
           strFile.Name = Replace(Replace(strNewFile,"*",""),"/","")  & ".xml"
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry Nathan, Newbie to this site, I have now accepted the answer but unable to upvote due to being new here. But your help was very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When i get my reputation above 15 i will come back and upvote. Cheers

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words to realize why a solution to the problem has to deal with more illegal characters and should handle duplicate file names caused by deleting different bad characters.